# Can't access Ajax Accordion Pane's Content

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, accordion

I'm using an `Accordion` with a `HiddenField` and another `Accordion` in it's panes like below:

```
<asp:Accordion ID="accFuncPerm" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accheaderfun"
    ContentCssClass="acccontfun" OnItemDataBound="accFuncPerm_ItemDataBound"
    RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="-1">
    <headertemplate>
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nmFuncionalidade")%>
        </headertemplate>
    <contenttemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfIDF" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idFuncionalidade")%>' />
            <asp:Accordion ID="accPagPerm" runat="server" HeaderCssClass="accheader" ContentCssClass="acccont"
                RequireOpenedPane="false" SelectedIndex="-1" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accheadersel" 
                OnItemCommand="accPagPerm_OnItemCommand" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="false" OnItemDataBound="accPagPerm_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nmPagina")%>'  
                        CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idPagina")%>' Width="100%" />                                    
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "idPagina")%>' />
                    <asp:Table ID="tblGrupoAcaoPagina" runat="server" CssClass="gv" GridLines="Both">
                        <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="tblHeader" runat="server">
                        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    </asp:Table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:Accordion>
        </contenttemplate>
</asp:Accordion>
```

On *PostBack* I access its selected pane:

`AccordionPane pane = accFuncPerm.Panes[accFuncPerm.SelectedIndex];`

But, when I try to find its controls it fails.

```
Accordion accPagPerm = (Accordion)pane.FindControl("accPagPerm");
pane = accPagPerm.Panes[int.Parse(txtAcc.Text)];
HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)pane.FindControl("hfID");
```

The panel I find comes with empty content and the *hiddenfield* is **null**.

Do anyone know the reason, and could please provide me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `Accordion` has a two `AccordionContentPanel` instances in Controls, one for the header, and the other for the content.  The content `AccordionContentPanel` has the values you are looking for:

```
protected void accFuncPerm_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    AccordionContentPanel acpContent;
    AccordionPane aPane = accFuncPerm.Panes[accFuncPerm.SelectedIndex];
    Control[] controls;

    //Find accPagPerm
    controls = new Control[aPane.Controls.Count];
    aPane.Controls.CopyTo(controls, 0);
    acpContent = (AccordionContentPanel)controls.Single(c => c.FindControl("accPagPerm") != null);
    Accordion accPagPerm = (Accordion)acpContent.FindControl("accPagPerm");

    //Find hfID
    aPane = accPagPerm.Panes[int.Parse(txtAcc.Text)];
    controls = new Control[aPane.Controls.Count];
    aPane.Controls.CopyTo(controls, 0);
    acpContent = (AccordionContentPanel)controls.Single(c => c.FindControl("hfID") != null);
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)acpContent.FindControl("hfID");
}
```

You will need to check for nulls and that the data types are as expected, but this will get you started.

On a side note: you could get rid of the `controls` variable, but then you would need to calculate the ID of the content `AccordionContentPanel`.  It seems to follow the format *<Accordion.ID>*_Pane_*<PaneIndex>*_content where *<Accordian.ID>* is the id of the `Accordion` which owns the panel and *<PaneIndex>* is the index of the panel in the `Accordion`'s `Panel` property.